# Why was I downvoted for a correct, well-explained answer?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, specific-answer

I'm new here and learning the ropes, so if I'm missing something, please let me know.

I want to know why [my answer to this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18104/20) was downvoted despite the fact that it was correct and I had explained my reasoning. The other short answer (Quark's) had a mildly similar explanation (I also happened to have used the word "rectangle"), but believe me, I didn't steal it from him.

If it was downvoted because it was considered a duplicate, then why wasn't it deleted already? And besides, why are a lot of answers with very similar reasoning (and only mildly similar explanations) upvoted instead?

Edit: just updated the answer.

Comment: Never mind, someone commented below it. I decided to delete my answer until I manage to correct it.

Comment: I've just added an edit. Let's see if they think much of it.

Comment: Still annoyed that someone else got away with making the same apparent mistake.

Comment: Sucks that I'm now on some people's idiot list.

Comment: No one has put you on their idiot list. The problem is, there's no way that the people who downvoted you will know that you've edited your answer.

Comment: @mmking Except if you know who DV. If that person left a comment on your post (which would be the polite thing to do), then you can comment there yourself using the @ username to send an alert to that user.

Answer (score 8):

Ideally, down-voters should leave a comment to explain (or up-vote a comment of another who explained already), but the world is not always ideal. Don't be too discouraged by DVs. Yes, they *should* make you think what you can potentially do better, but they should not cause you anger or frustration. Some votes are justified, others aren't. (True in both up and down directions.)

I think you did the right thing if you're *puzzled* (excuse the pun): Add a comment asking for explanation.